# How to use React-widget Dropdownlist with groupby attribute

Tags: html, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I need to use react-widgets dropdownlist with groupby attribute.
A typical example of this would be;

```
<Multiselect
  data=[{name:'Dan' lastName:'Black'}, {name:'Man' lastName:'Black'}]
  textField='name'
  groupBy='lastName'
/>
```

But the data array i have of is of a completely different structure. like;

```
[
   {
     name:'test one',
     objects: [{key:'my key', value:'my value'},
                {key:'my key1', value:'my value1'}
                {key:'my key2', value:'my value2'}]
   },
   {
     name:'test two',
     objects: [{key:'my key', value:'my value'},
                {key:'my key1', value:'my value1'}
                {key:'my key2', value:'my value2'}]
   }
]
```

And i need the 'key' to be the value displayed in the list and groupby on 'name'.

Is this possible to achieve or just completely stupid and i have to restructure it totally?

Each objects array is honestly 100 or more objects long.. so i prefer not to restructure it again due to performance issue.

Thanks in advance, All ideas are welcome!

**UPDATE:**

```
<DropdownList
    data = {
    [{
        repoName: 'google repository',
        objects: [
            {
                key: 'mykey',
                method: 'my meth',
                value: 'my val'
            },
            {
                key: 'mykey2',
                method: 'my meth2',
                value: 'my val2'
            }]
    }]}
     textField='objects.key'
     placeholder={placeholder}
     groupBy='repoName'
   />
```

Gives something like;

```
google repository
[Object Object]
```

How could iterate that object array to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding, what you can do is create a different structure for data using your existing one.

```
const data = [{
  name: 'test one',
  objects: [{
    key: 'my key',
    value: 'my value'
  }, {
    key: 'my key1',
    value: 'my value1'
  } {
    key: 'my key2',
    value: 'my value2'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'test two',
  objects: [{
    key: 'my key',
    value: 'my value'
  }, {
    key: 'my key1',
    value: 'my value1'
  } {
    key: 'my key2',
    value: 'my value2'
  }]
}]
const newData = []
data.forEach((element) => {
  const name = element.name
  if (element.objects && element.object.length) {
    element.objects.forEach((keyValueData) => {
      newData.push({
        name,
        key: keyValueData.key,
        value: keyValueData.value,
      })
    })
  }
})


< Multiselect
data = {
  newData
}
textField = 'name'
groupBy = 'key' / >
```

This way, it should solve your issue.Mind brackets not tested the code

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, I was considering this as well. But each objects array would contain more than 100 items.. and re-rendering this Dropdown list needs to happen quite often. Do you think this would cause a huge performance issue?

Comment: Look we dont have any oprtion if the Modal api is like that. obviously extra processing will take time, but there is no way until the api itself give us any way